# What's the difference between a rotation at byte level vs a rotation at bit level?

Tags: cryptography, byte, computer-science, bit, theory

Could you please give some examples.
I don't understand in class because I think they give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

### Bit level rotation

`11110000` **original**
`01111000` **rotated once**
`00111100` **rotated twice**
`00011110` **rotated thrice**

### Byte level rotation

`11110000 00001111 11110000` **original**
`11110000 11110000 00001111` **rotated once**
`00001111 11110000 11110000` **rotated twice**
`11110000 00001111 11110000` **rotated thrice**